# I have a list with 7 elements in Python, but the len operator returns a length of 1

Tags: python

New to Python, this is my first application.  I've been staring at this a while, and I'm sure I have some fundamental misunderstanding about what's going on.

In this example I have a list of 7 str (entries), and an assignment statement:

`listLen = len(entries)`

Followed by a breakpoint, and below is a screen capture showing the debugger where listLen is assigned a value of 1, and entries is a {list: 7}

[image]

I'd expect len(entries) to return a value of 7, but I can't seem to get the expected behavior.  What am I missing?

UPDATE: I thought the answer was in the for loop modifying the list but apparently not.

If I set a breakpoint before assigning entries and single step through with the debugger *including* the for loop everything looks good and works.

If I set a breakpoint ON the for loop and single step once, entries again appears to be a {list: 7} but the len(entries) appears to be 1.  The for loop executes one loop and exits.

The deep copy entriesCopy I made for debug is used nowhere else, and gets changed to [''], but I assume that since it's not used it gets optimized out or garbage collected, though it doesn't when single-stepping from an earlier breakpoint.

After breaking on the 'for' loop and single stepping once to the beginning of the 'while' loop:

[image]

Why would single stepping through the code work fine, but breaking at the for loop cause len(entries) to be wrong?

Single stepping from earlier breakpoint works fine, and the program returns the correct result:
[image]

I'm still struggling to get a minimum reproducible sample of code.

Here's more of the code:

```
        entries = self.userQuery.getEntries()
        entriesCopy = copy.deepcopy(self.userQuery.getEntries())
        entryList = list()
        listLen = len(entries)
        for ii in range(0,listLen):
            while ("\n\n") in entries[ii]: entries[ii]=entries[ii].replace("\n\n","\n") #strip double newlines
            while ("\t") in entries[ii]: entries[ii] = entries[ii].replace("\t", "")  # strip tabs
            entryList=entries[ii].split("\n")
            while("" in entryList): entryList.remove('')
            self.SCPIDictionary[self.instructions[ii][1].replace("\n","")]=entryList;
```

Comment: Please provide more information and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). `len()` on a list _should_ produce the length of the list.

Comment: `entries` seems to be `['']`, a list with one element: an empty string. Can you use calls to `print()` to debug this instead of relying on the tooltip that may be wrong?

Comment: Please include code, not an image of code.

Comment: @L.Grozinger The image was only to show the debugger's impression of what the variables are.  I'm working on trying to get a small reproducible example, otherwise I don't know how much code other than listLen = len(entries) to include.

Comment: Could you add previous definitions and context of the variable and its sources?

Comment: @MarijnvanVliet Thanks, I hadn't noticed that given the tooltip hover showing what I would expect, which is a list of 7 strings.  I think that's the important clue here.

Comment: when you put the breakpoint on the for loop, it does NOT break before the first iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look a little higher in your debug output- you can see on line 42 `entries: ['']`

I can't read the code in your for loop so I don't know whats happening, but you seem to be modifying the list in there. If you use the "hover" to look at the value, you would get the current value of that variable. You set the breakpoint on the "for" part of the loop- try setting it on the first line of the loop and the line before the loop and watch for that entries list to get mutated.

--- edit ---
You provided more code. Its... kind of insane. Why are you modifying the "entries" object repeatedly in while loops? Then you copy the entry into another object, and then replace a value in some dictionary with the entry you just copied (with the key determined after running string transformations on a matrix dictionary?)

Two things-

1. To debug this, I am concerned about the types. Does "getEntries" actually return a list of strings, or is it a resultproxy or something similar? Sqlalchemy for example does not actually return a list. The python debugger is great, but you're doing so much mutation here- instead, lets use print statements. do `print(entries)` after every line. That will let you see when things are changing, and at least how many times your loop is executing. If it is something like a result proxy, as an example, after you finished iterating over it, there may just not be anything left in there when you look at it in the debugger.
2. consider this- instead of modifying all these mutable objects, pull out the values and modify those. As a rough draft-

```
    for entry in entries:
      values = []
      for val in entry.replace("\n\n", "\n").replace("\t, "").split("\n"):
        if val:
          values.append(val)
      self.CCPIDictionary[something?] = values
```

Comment: Thanks to the comment above I did notice the entries: [''] above, and it led me to the same conclusion as you, problem solved.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually not that simple, I added an update to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The answer, which you couldn't have known since I didn't yet give enough information, seems to be (still validating) that I wasn't using wait_window properly in the tkinter user popup, so there was kind of a concurrency issue with the popup not being properly modal and the rest of the code running before user input was done.  That's why it works when single stepping and not when running, or not when the breakpoint is set past the point where the len of the list is assigned.

Comment: Oddly, it seemed to not hit the early breakpoint (and looked like it was waiting for user input) when run with the PyCharm IDE.  It wasn't until I switched to Visual Studio that I immediately saw the problem. (Breakpoint hit before user data was entered.)

Comment: And thanks for the much more elegant suggestion on how to deal with getting the entries into the dictionary.  You may have guessed I'm not a programmer, I'm an analog hardware engineer who needs to write code on a very infrequent basis.